# How to compute integration on product mesuareg space?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, polar-coordinates

Let $((0, \infty), \mathcal{M}_1, \mu_1)$ be measure space, where $\mathcal{M}_1$ be Lebesgue measurable sets in $(0, \infty)$ and $$\mu_1(E)=\int_{E} r^{d-1} dr$$ be a measure on $\mathcal{M_1}.$

Let unit sphere $S^{d-1}=\{x\in \mathbb R^d:|x|=1\}.$ Given $E\subset S^{d-1},$ we define $\tilde{E}=\{ x\in \mathbb R^d: x/|x|\in E, 0<|x|<1\}.$

We say $E\in \mathcal{M}_2$ exactly when $\tilde{E}$ is a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb R^d.$  We define
$$\mu_2(E)=\sigma(E)=d\cdot m(\tilde{E})$$
where $m$ is a Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^d$

Then $(S^{d-1}, \mathcal{M}_2, \mu_2=\sigma)$ is a measure space.

> My Question: How to verify following integration formula for polar coordinates:
> $$\int_{\mathbb R^d} f(x) dx= \int_{S^{d-1}} \left( \int_0^{\infty} f(r\gamma) r^{d-1} dr \right) d\sigma(\gamma)$$
> when $f=\chi_{E}$ where $E$ is Lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb R^d$

My attempt: Let $f=\chi_{E}.$ Then LHS= $m(E)$
To compute RHS, we take $E=E_1\times E_2$ where $E_1\in \mathcal{M}_1$ and $E_2\in \mathcal{M}_2$.  Now I do not know: how to compute

$$\int_0^{\infty} \chi_{E_1\times E_2}(r\gamma) r^{d-1}dr$$